# radiobuttonfor with data- with strange behaviour

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i'm trying to make a checkbox with bool value from my model. it works, but now I'm trying to add some data-* field to the checkbox In order to add parameters to the nice [bootstrap-switch](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html) component, and it doesn't work:

```
<input data-val="true" id="actionList_0__efficacity" name="actionList[0].efficacity" type="radio" value="{ data_on_text = YEAH}">
```

And it should be

```
<input data-val="true" id="actionList_0__efficacity" name="actionList[0].efficacity" type="radio" data-on-text = "YEAH">
```

so this is what I've done:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.efficacity, new { data_on_text = "YEAH" } )
```

I already tried the EditorFor for I can't put data_ with EditorFor apparently...

Thanks for the help

Comment: That's because the overload of RadioButtonFor that takes html attributes has three parameters, expression, value, and attributes.  You only have two, so it's using the two parameter overload which is treating your "data_on_text" as a directly literal value for the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html and the helper you have shown don't quite match up (the html suggests your generating radio buttons for a collection because it contains an indexer or perhaps you have an `EditorTemplate` for the type represented by property `actionList`?) but the 2nd parameter of `RadioButtonFor()` is the object that sets the 'value' attribute. You need to change the helper to

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.efficacity, someValue, new { data_on_text = "YEAH" } )
```

where `someValue` is the value that will be assigned to property `efficacity` (for example a `string` or an `enum`)

Comment: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.efficacity, false, new { data_on_text = "YES", data_off_text = "NO" }) is my solution, thanks again

Comment: Umm. I was a bit puzzled when you _"make a checkbox with bool value"_ :). But will that work on its own? - you would need a second one with `true` otherwise it will always post back `false`

Comment: Yes I wanted to use checkbox in fact.. I don't know why I was talking about radio...